# Create table with current_timestamp and update it with every row update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

at the moment I´m using this code, to create a new table and insert/update the users captcha:

```
    if ($result) {
        echo "$captcha";
        $queryInsertCaptcha = mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO xf_captcha (username, captcha) VALUES ('$user', '$captcha') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE captcha = '$captcha'" );
    } else {
        echo "Tabelle muss noch erstellt werden.";
        $queryCreateCaptchaTable = mysql_query ( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xf_captcha` (
            `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
            `captcha` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
            'timestamp',
            PRIMARY KEY  (`username`) );
        ");
    }
```

Now I would like to add a timestamp, because I want to block captcha codes which are older than x.

How can I create the MySQLs TIMESTAMP Type with the Default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ?

How can I tell MySQL to update the timestamp if "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" runs ?
Or should I drop the data and insert the new one ?

Comment: **Careful!** Your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com). Also, the `mysql_*` functions are [old and deprecated and should not be used anymore](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). Please have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli), which are better [MySQL API choices](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Why do you use SQL for this? Store the captcha code to a session and that's it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: yeah, I know. But for this it should still work. Because It only allows insert. I just checked out PDO for another script with SELECT and WHERE. Now I´m gonna check out MySQLi, too. :/

Comment: why not you use the timestamp function in table.

Comment: thats the one I want to use. Just don´t know how to create it via. php.

Comment: regarding to sessions. I´m a complete php noob, but as far as I know sessions only work for the same browser like cookies. The script is run by a java application, which tells the user his captcha code, wich allows him to register within a forum.

Comment: yeap you are right session do work with cookies .But why not you use the separate table for new users and handle them there i mean to signup form.

Comment: and use random number function for captcha each time a new user will come it will get a new captcha for registration

Answer (score 2):

If you are using phpmyadmin Than its quite easy go in database and choose the Timestamp type to timestamp field it will do the rest try it.

Comment: I know, but I want php to handle this.

Comment: i recommend to do it from phpmyadmin that is accurate and easy to use than if and else your query

Comment: yeah it will work automatically install xampp and check out they have made php easy for you don't complicate it for your self

Comment: I mean the creation of the table has to work automatically. Still looking for the solution to create it.

Comment: what engine are you using and what os are you using i am going to help you out i am in your services

Answer (score 1):

For part 1 of your question
"How can I create the MySQLs TIMESTAMP Type with the Default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
read the online manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Regarding the 2nd part of question, I'm not sure why you're allowing duplicate key conflicts to occur, might be better to avoid these.

Your code should probably check if the key exists before trying to create a new record
Then have 2 separate queries one for a username that exists already, another for a username that does not exist

MySQL also has a feature for refreshing timestamps automatically on update

Comment: k, thanks. How can I create the timestamp field with the auto update via. php ?